# wp_posts.id values over 9 digits cause posts and permissions issues

Tags: php, mysql, wordpress, nginx

This insert fails and causes the problems above:

```
INSERT INTO `wp_posts` (`ID`, ... ) 
VALUES (33145694077, ... );
```

But this insert works just fine:

```
INSERT INTO `wp_posts` (`ID`, ... )
VALUES (145694077, ... );
```

Only difference is that I killed off the first two numbers from the id's INSERT value. (`145694077` instead of `33145694077`).

Here's the table structure for wp_posts:

```
`wp_posts` ( 
    `ID` bigint(20) unsigned NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT, 
    ...
) 
ENGINE=MyISAM DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8;
```

I'm only having this problem when I'm trying to import my posts to WP Engine. My MAMP install, and my other server environment (Apache / CENTOS 6.5) handle these imports just fine. WPE uses nginx, I know. I guess I don't know enough to decide whether or not an issue exists there!

Any thoughts, similar experiences?

[This sad, unsolved thread was all I could find on the subject.](http://wordpress.org/support/topic/all-posts-show-as-no-title-after-db-restore)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The largest signed 32-bit integer is 2,147,483,647. 33,145,694,077 is greater than that, but 145,694,077 is less than it.

I'll bet your MAMP environment and your other server are running a 64-bit operating system with appropriate versions of MySQL and PHP, while the server giving you problems is only 32-bit.

Comment: That sounds _real_ spot on. Gonna try this out tomorrow and accept this answer when it proves correct. ;)

Comment: Hey! Wanted to let you know this was indeed the root of the problem. I ended up having to write a script to start counting again from 0. https://gist.github.com/cam5/9180843.

Comment: Wow, that's one of those things I always knew could happen in theory but never saw happen in real life. Guess this switch to 64-bit didn't happen a minute too soon. Glad it worked out for you.

Comment: And to think it all happened because the client's tumblr posts kept their IDs when we imported years back. I think it also set the auto_increment to something like 10,000. So, yeah, I was on an inevitable road to headache there. Thanks for your help!